# Proof of $\mathrm{C\ell}_{p+k,q}(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathrm{C\ell}_{p,q+k}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: clifford-algebras

The following result is mentioned in a [dissertation](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/handle/2142/44335)

$$\mathrm{C\ell}_{p+k,q}(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathrm{C\ell}_{p,q+k}(\mathbb{R}),
\text{ , if } p-q\equiv 1 \text{(mod 4)}$$

However, since that dissertation has many typos, and this result is only used
once, I am quite unsure of its validity. Do someone have a reference for it?

P.S. I have searched this [book](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198782926.001.0001/acprof-9780198782926) and found nothing.

Comment: The claim is made here as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras#Symmetries. Perhaps the sources there would help.

Comment: Yes I also checked. But no explicit formula for this.